# Application Load Balancers Requests Hanging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-alb

In my aws env requests are hanging at the ALB for some reason. I haven't been able to identify a cause yet aside from Cache hanging requests there and possibly the session write being left open causing it to wait. what might be the possible reason for of it ,Are there other diagnostic tools for recommendation to add into the stack to try to debug this issue?

Comment: ALBs are pretty reliable. I'd be looking at its configuration and if / how it's routing requests to the target servers.

Comment: Is expire certificate causes an issue in ALB  ?? I checked the route , seems that everything works fine in spite of alb having the packet drop issue ??

Comment: An ALB rarely drops packets. We once had an ALB with a hardware issue that had weird issues, but that's one in five years of working with AWS. The problem will be misconfiguration of the ALB or issues with the target servers. https certificates are handed in AWS certificate manager, if you generate them in ACM they are auto renewed.

Comment: Hello Tim, we only face the issue of packet drops and REJECT requests at this time in one of our ALB , can you pl explain a bit what might be the possible issues with it ??

Comment: If it's not ALB configuration or target server configuration I think you have two choices 1) Terminate the ALB and create a new one. There's not a big chance this will work, but it will shift it to new hardware 2) Get AWS business support for a month, they're excellent and will work through this with you. The cost of the support tends to be good value given how much downtime or problems cost.